# Is it possible to do an immediate speculative retry towards the REMOTE datacenter?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

My cassandra cluster is hosted on two datacenters. Not only are they separated by some latency, at times either of them might become temporarily unavailable.

EACH_QUORUM is not an option as it is both too slow and not available enough.
LOCAL_QUORUM is an option and what I'm currently doing, but it doesn't tolerate the local datacenter being unavailable.

Is it possible to configure the java driver to do an immediate speculative retry against the remote cluster?

As far as I understand this would send the request to both datacenters and as soon as any of them returns (which would normally be the local one); the driver would return.

Perhaps I would also have to combine this with a RetryPolicy or LoadBalancingPolicy that tolerates that either the LOCAL or REMOTE datacenter is temporarily unavailable.

Answer (score 1):

In theory it wouldn't work because the same query plan is used for the life of the request/query.

If you recall, the driver generates a query plan where all live hosts in the local DC are preferred with remote nodes added last. In a cluster with 2 DCs and 3 nodes/DC, the first 3 hosts in the query plan will always be the 3 nodes in the local DC so the remote nodes will not tried for speculative execution.

In any case, it sounds like you're looking for a software solution for what is an infrastructure problem and it's not a viable fix. At best, it is going to be an unpredictable workaround.

You really need to address the underlying issue. Cheers!